# Searching Excel Data Set based on Between Dates

Tags: excel

I Have two Data Sets as Follows

Data Set One

```
ID        Date From        Date To
5001      06/12/1999       08/1/2000
5001      08/08/2002       09/09/2004
```

---

Data Set Two

```
ID          Date From        Date To      Res
5001       01/01/1999       01/01/2001     E
5001       02/01/2001       01/01/2010     O
```

I would like to use the ID from Data Set one to find and return the Res based on the dates. The Current Employee Has been holding the position 5001 from the specified dates in Data Set One and I would like to Match it with Data Set Two to Understand The Position Res

Note: The Data Set greater than 10,000 Rows each

Comment: It looks as if the answers would be 'E' and 'O' because the 'E' row in data set 2  includes the whole date range in the first row of data set one and similarly with the 'O' row. Could it ever happen that only part of the date range in one of the rows of data set one is included in 'E' or 'O'? Could one of the date ranges in data set one include both 'E' and 'O' ranges ? Or am I making it too difficult?

Comment: It can't happen to have two different outcomes. The dates would fall either in E or O only but never in both.

Answer (score 1):

To see if there was at least one "E" or "O" range on Sheet 2 that fully contained a range with the same ID on Sheet 1 I would use:-

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B,"<="&B2,Sheet2!C:C,">="&C2,Sheet2!D:D,"E"),"E",IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B,"<="&B2,Sheet2!C:C,">="&C2,Sheet2!D:D,"O"),"O",""))
```

starting in cell D2 of Sheet 1.

But to see if there was at least one range in Sheet 2 that overlapped with a range with the same ID on sheet 1 I would use:-

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B,"<="&C2,Sheet2!C:C,">="&B2,Sheet2!D:D,"E"),"E",IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B,"<="&C2,Sheet2!C:C,">="&B2,Sheet2!D:D,"O"),"O",""))
```